# New Google Action with date/time comparison

Tags: actions-on-google

I need your help!
I have to write a new Action for Google Assistant. If you ask Google the same question in different hours of the day, Google have to reply with different phrases.
Which is the better way for develop this project?
Thank you very much!

Comment: StackOverflow works best when you have a concrete problem that you have tried to solve, but are still running into issues. I suggest you update your question to show what approaches you have considered or tried, what isn't working and why, and possibly code that you've attempted to get working. See [How Do I Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).